# Javascript isPunct function

Tags: javascript, function

I'm currently coding a Command Line program for function isPunct in Javascript and struggling to both start & completely finish it. Here's what I have so far:

```
function isPunct(str) {
   var str  = ".,:!?;";

   if (/\pPunct/.test(str)) {
     alert("Character is punctuation")
   }

   else {
      alert("Character is not punctuation")
   }
}
```

It's going through the console just fine, but isn't actually picking out the punctuation. Please help if you can! And thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think `Punct` is a real thing in a regular expression, you probably just want to check for a literal period `/\./`

Answer (score 1):

```js
function isPunct() {
   //var str  = "a.,:!?;"; -> false because of a
   var str  = ".,:!?;";

   if (/^(\.|\,|\!|\?|\:|\;|\"|\'|\-|\(|\))*$/g.test(str)) {
     alert("Character is punctuation")
   }

   else {
      alert("Character is not punctuation")
   }
}
isPunct();
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if you were attempting to use Unicode property escapes (`\p{UnicodePropertyName=UnicodePropertyValue}`), which are not currently a part of the JavaScript standard. There is [a proposal to add this functionality](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-unicode-property-escapes), but it has thus far only reached stage 2 of the TC39 process.

However, [Mathias Bynens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/96656/mathias-bynens) has created a wonderful tool called `regexpu` that will transpile these property escapes to their standard equivalents. I doubt all of the codepoints in the result are necessary to you, so feel free to shorten the list of characters as you see fit.

([Permalink to the ES5 equivalent of `/^\p{Punctuation}*$/u`.](https://mothereff.in/regexpu#input=%2F%5Cp%7BPunctuation%7D%2Fu&unicodePropertyEscape=1))

```js
var onlyPunctuation = /^(?:[!-#%-\*,-/:;\?@\[-\]_\{\}\xA1\xA7\xAB\xB6\xB7\xBB\xBF\u037E\u0387\u055A-\u055F\u0589\u058A\u05BE\u05C0\u05C3\u05C6\u05F3\u05F4\u0609\u060A\u060C\u060D\u061B\u061E\u061F\u066A-\u066D\u06D4\u0700-\u070D\u07F7-\u07F9\u0830-\u083E\u085E\u0964\u0965\u0970\u0AF0\u0DF4\u0E4F\u0E5A\u0E5B\u0F04-\u0F12\u0F14\u0F3A-\u0F3D\u0F85\u0FD0-\u0FD4\u0FD9\u0FDA\u104A-\u104F\u10FB\u1360-\u1368\u1400\u166D\u166E\u169B\u169C\u16EB-\u16ED\u1735\u1736\u17D4-\u17D6\u17D8-\u17DA\u1800-\u180A\u1944\u1945\u1A1E\u1A1F\u1AA0-\u1AA6\u1AA8-\u1AAD\u1B5A-\u1B60\u1BFC-\u1BFF\u1C3B-\u1C3F\u1C7E\u1C7F\u1CC0-\u1CC7\u1CD3\u2010-\u2027\u2030-\u2043\u2045-\u2051\u2053-\u205E\u207D\u207E\u208D\u208E\u2308-\u230B\u2329\u232A\u2768-\u2775\u27C5\u27C6\u27E6-\u27EF\u2983-\u2998\u29D8-\u29DB\u29FC\u29FD\u2CF9-\u2CFC\u2CFE\u2CFF\u2D70\u2E00-\u2E2E\u2E30-\u2E44\u3001-\u3003\u3008-\u3011\u3014-\u301F\u3030\u303D\u30A0\u30FB\uA4FE\uA4FF\uA60D-\uA60F\uA673\uA67E\uA6F2-\uA6F7\uA874-\uA877\uA8CE\uA8CF\uA8F8-\uA8FA\uA8FC\uA92E\uA92F\uA95F\uA9C1-\uA9CD\uA9DE\uA9DF\uAA5C-\uAA5F\uAADE\uAADF\uAAF0\uAAF1\uABEB\uFD3E\uFD3F\uFE10-\uFE19\uFE30-\uFE52\uFE54-\uFE61\uFE63\uFE68\uFE6A\uFE6B\uFF01-\uFF03\uFF05-\uFF0A\uFF0C-\uFF0F\uFF1A\uFF1B\uFF1F\uFF20\uFF3B-\uFF3D\uFF3F\uFF5B\uFF5D\uFF5F-\uFF65]|\uD800[\uDD00-\uDD02\uDF9F\uDFD0]|\uD801\uDD6F|\uD802[\uDC57\uDD1F\uDD3F\uDE50-\uDE58\uDE7F\uDEF0-\uDEF6\uDF39-\uDF3F\uDF99-\uDF9C]|\uD804[\uDC47-\uDC4D\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDCBE-\uDCC1\uDD40-\uDD43\uDD74\uDD75\uDDC5-\uDDC9\uDDCD\uDDDB\uDDDD-\uDDDF\uDE38-\uDE3D\uDEA9]|\uD805[\uDC4B-\uDC4F\uDC5B\uDC5D\uDCC6\uDDC1-\uDDD7\uDE41-\uDE43\uDE60-\uDE6C\uDF3C-\uDF3E]|\uD807[\uDC41-\uDC45\uDC70\uDC71]|\uD809[\uDC70-\uDC74]|\uD81A[\uDE6E\uDE6F\uDEF5\uDF37-\uDF3B\uDF44]|\uD82F\uDC9F|\uD836[\uDE87-\uDE8B]|\uD83A[\uDD5E\uDD5F])*$/

function isPunct (string) {
    return onlyPunctuation.test(string)
}

console.log(isPunct('.,:!?;')) //=> true
console.log(isPunct('letters')) //=> false
```